# PayPal Legacy MPL - Chained Payment - Guest Checkout

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I've found several conflicting views on the internet with regards to if this is possible.

I have a verified paypal business account and have added the legacy MPL into my company's mobile application. Using the express checkout to process a chained payment, the user is forced to log in and use their PayPal balance as the only form of payment.

There is no option to supply a credit card and pay directly. There is no option once logged in to pay with an attached credit card.

This is from the sandbox perspective, which has mock credit cards on each mock user account.

Can anyone, who knows the actual answer, if a chain payment with the legacy MPL with a registered verified business account supports guest checkout on mobile (Android in this case).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, guest checkout is available with Adaptive Payments.  I have a [sample Chained Pay request setup here](http://paypal.angelleye.com/paypal-php-library/samples/Pay-Chained.php).  Loading that you'll see the successful response which includes a RedirectURL.  Copy/paste that RedirectURL into your browser address bar to load it and you'll see it sends you to PayPal, at which point this is what I see...

[image]

You can see it provides the option to either login and pay or just pay with a credit/debit card.

Comment: Yeah I spoke to a paypal rep on Github about this. The long story short is that MPL (mobile payments library, legacy) does support adaptive payments but does not support guest checkout (credit card). I got around this by doing a payRequest on the server and launching an external intent on the mobile device to browse to the paypal website with the appropriate payKey generated from the server's payRequest. 

It's not pretty, but it's functional, and there was no other way to have what I required.

Thanks though.